# Enabling Digest Auth in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core, authentication, .net-6.0

I am working on creating a virtual device for as a tool our dev team can use to simulate actual hardware integration. The plan is that this can be spun up in a docker container and even spin up multiple virtual devices to simulate load testing development and other things. one feature is that the API Auth uses Digest Auth with username and password.

Most examples are for the client side, any good examples that can be helpful, this is a I know this is not the most secure implementation.

Client .NET 4.5 call:

```
public static HttpClient Client(Device device, int timeoutInSecond)
{
    var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
           {
                    Credentials = new NetworkCredential(device.Credentials.UserName,device.Credentials.Password)            
           };
    
    var client = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = new Uri(netLinkDevice.Url) }; 
    client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(timeoutInSecond);

    return client;
}
```

Call in Postman:

[image: postman call]

Comment: Isn't this the way provided in the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/basic-and-digest-authentication)?

Comment: That document is how to call an api, not setting up the api